# Use run test in VS Code Go extension tries to run tests in package main

Tags: go, visual-studio-code

Hi I am using Go version 1.16:

```
$ go version
go version go1.16.2 darwin/amd64
```

```
# .zshrc
#
# Go Setup

export GOPATH="$HOME/go"
export PATH=$PATH:$GOPATH/bin
```

and have this setup:

```
tree ./
./
├── go.mod
├── sum.go
└── sum_test.go
```

```
// go.mod
module mysum

go 1.16
```

```
// sum.go
package mysum

func Sum(numbers [5]int) int {
    sum := 0
    for _, number := range numbers {
        sum += number
    }

    return sum
}
```

```
// sum_test.go
package mysum

import "testing"

func TestSum(t *testing.T) {
    numbers := [5]int{1, 2, 3, 4, 5}

    got := Sum(numbers)
    want := 15

    if got != want {
        t.Errorf("got %d want %d given, %v", got, want, numbers)
    }
}
```

And when I click run test (above function `TestSum`) in below screenshot, I got an error says:

[image]

```
Running tool: /usr/local/go/bin/go test -timeout 30s -run ^TestSum$ main

package main is not in GOROOT (/usr/local/go/src/main)
```

If I manually run `go test -run ^TestSum$` in the folder it works fine:

```
$ go test -run ^TestSum$ mysum

PASS
ok      mysum   0.005s
```

Does anyone know if I miss any configuration for [Go with VS Code](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/languages/go)?

How do I tell the extension to run tests in `mysum` package instead of `main` package?

```
$ /usr/local/go/bin/go test -timeout 30s -run ^TestSum$ mysum
```

Go extension v0.23.2, VS Code Version: 1.54.2

Comment: Do you have a settings.json inside the .vscode directory or a global settings.json? Try verifying if you have set this config var `go.testFlags`

Answer (score 0):

Have you changed the module name in go.mod from `main` to `mysum` before running 'run test'? Are you still seeing an issue if you reload the window? (Cmd+Shift+P -> "Developer: Reload Window")

I found an issue in the current go extension https://github.com/golang/vscode-go/issues/1373 but I am not yet sure if this is the same issue you are seeing.

(sorry - I meant to add as a comment, but I don't have enough credit to add my reply as a comment :-))